# Can AWS Sagemaker training instances swap virtual memory to disk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, virtual-memory

I have a training algorithm that needs to load a huge dataset into memory and then translate it into another format. After this operation I can free the memory used to hold the first copy of the dataset. This single operation takes a fraction of my total compute time but requires allocating twice as much memory as my dataset consumes. Has anyone had success swapping to disk for cases like this?

I understand that Sagemaker is running my docker container on the training instances and I have tried passing `ContainerArguments=["--memory-swap", "1g"]` to the constructor of the `Estimator`. I logged the output of `swapon -s` before and after this change but it does not produce any output in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Estimator's `container_arguments` is to pass arguments to the entry point (`container_entry_point`), rather than to container runtime, so `--memory-swap` you are passing is not taking expected effect.